# Where to place logic in a Class Base View?

Tags: python, django

I want to understand where in a Class Base View I would do the logic for the following:

[image]

Basically, I want to check if the user has an account if so forward them to URL A, else URL B. However, I'm not 100% sure if get_success_url() would be the best place for this in a CBV or if Django has something that already caters for this usecase. I have seen other CBV likes RedirectView I have tried this but lost the scope. Keep in mind that I need to pass the user id.

This is where I have gotten to so far:

```
class CampaignView(BaseUpdateView):
    form_class = UserLookUpFrom
    model = Campaign


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CampaignView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # context['form'] = AppUserLookUpFrom

        return context


    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the form is valid, in this case DON'T save it!
        """
        return super(CampaignView, self).form_valid(form)


    def get_success_url(self):

        """
        Returns the supplied URL.
        """
        if self.success_url:
            url = self.success_url % self.object.__dict__
        else:
            try:
                currect_user = Campaign.object.get_user_by_email(EMAIL HERE DONT KNOW HOW TO GET THIS YET FROM FORM)
                if currect_user:
                         url = reverse('campaigns_login', args=(self.object.id,'self.userid'))
                else:
                         url = reverse('campaigns_register', args=(self.object.id)



            except AttributeError:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                    "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define"
                    " a get_absolute_url method on the Model.")
        return url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be on post of the CampaignView:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   form= self.form_class(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
      user_email= form.cleaned_data['email']
      user_of_campaign= Campaign.objects.filter(email= user_email)
      if len(user_of_campaign)>0:
         return redirect('/login', user_of_campaign[0].id)
      else: 
         return redirect('/register')
      return super(CampaignView, self).form_valid(form)
   return super(CampaignView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. could you explain the last two return supers? I don't see how the second one would work.

Comment: Second one for if the form is invalid then, the user will be returned to the initial form page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `form_valid` itself. Here is an untested code that should help explain the concept:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def form_valid(self, form):
    email = form.cleaned_data.get("email", "")
    prev_user = Campaign.object.filter(email=email)
    if prev_user:
       return redirect('campaigns_login', self.object.id, prev_user[0].userid)
    else:
       return redirect('campaigns_register', self.object.id)
```